# When using docker, I get DirectoryNotFoundException in PhysicalFileProvider in blazor

Tags: docker, blazor

I created a blazor project using .netcore3.1.

I use PhysicalFileProvider in startup.cs.

I ran it with docker using config in docker.

The build was successful, but an exception occurred during execution.

[image]

The docker file is as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Web/Web.csproj", "Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Web/Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Web"
RUN dotnet build "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

This is a docker file automatically generated by Visual Studio.

Why can't the program find the directory?
Or, is there another way to find the directory?

Comment: blazor-webassembly?

Comment: No, Server-side App